# Join two elements into a string type element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

In an array of objects `sorted`

```js
sorted = [{…}, {…}, {…}]
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {firstName: "john", lastName: "Doe", age: 36, gender: "male"}
1: {lastName: "Latt", age: 40, gender: "male"}
2: {firstName: "Tom", age: 22, gender: "male"}
```

How do I return an array which got `"firstName+' '+lastName"` if both exists,
if `firstName` or `lastName` is not given, return one of the existing values?

I want to use `.map.filter(true).join(' ')`

example:

```js
["john Doe", "Latt", "Tom"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need filter & join - It will unecessary affect performance.

If you need the answer to use the `join` and the `filter` functions answer of @Ever Dev is quite good

```js
var sorted = [ {firstName: "john", lastName: "Doe", age: 36, gender: "male"},
{lastName: "Latt", age: 40, gender: "male"},
{firstName: "Tom", age: 22, gender: "male"}
]


var result = sorted.map(val => (`${val.firstName ? val.firstName: ''} ${val.lastName? val.lastName: ''}`).trim() )
//.join(' ');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Readable code is often better than faster code. And just in this case, we can ignore it.

It looks much prettier and meaningful, isn't it?
`sort.map(item => [item.firstName, item.lastName].filter(v => !!v).join(' ')`

Comment: wanted to let you know I solved the question that I was stuck for 5 hours with the method you provided. thank you @israGab

Answer (score 1):

```js
const sort = [
    {firstName: "john", lastName: "Doe", age: 36, gender: "male"},
    {lastName: "Latt", age: 40, gender: "male"},
    {firstName: "Tom", age: 22, gender: "male"}
];

console.log( 
    sort.map(item => 
        [item.firstName, item.lastName].filter(v => !!v).join(' ')
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to `.map()` each item and apply your logic

```js
sorted.map(person => {
  return `${person.firstName}${person.firstName && person.lastName ? ' ' : ''}${person.lastName}`;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for is a map()

```
>     sorted.map(user => {
>         if (user.firstName && user.lastName) return user.firstName + " " + 
>           user.lastName
>         if (user.firstName) return user.firstName
>         if (user.lastName) return user.lastName
>         return ""
>     })
```